# How to combine/merge two JArrays in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I can't figure out how to concatenate two JArrays that I got by using JArray.Parse? The order of the arrays must be preserved i.e. the first array should be first and element in seconds should come afterwards.

Comment: That's the thing...I can't figure out what to do. I'm new to JSON.NET and was expecting an Append or Concatenate API, but dont see any?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add elements to one `JArray` by calling `JArray.Add(element)` where element comes from the second JArray. You'll need to loop over the second JArray to add all of these elements, but this will accomplish what you want:

```
for(int i=0; i<jarrayTwo.Count; i++)
{
    jarrayOne.Add(jarrayTwo[i]);
}
```

in the above example `jarrayOne` will now contain all of the first array's elements followed by the second array's elements in sequence. You can take a look through the [JArray documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/#) for further details.

Answer (score 46):

I used the [Merge](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Merge.htm) method, which modifies the original JArray:

```
 JArray test1 = JArray.Parse("[\"john\"]");
 JArray test2 = JArray.Parse("[\"doe\"]");
 test1.Merge(test2);
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the union method:

```
JArray test1 = JArray.Parse("[\"john\"]");
JArray test2 = JArray.Parse("[\"doe\"]");
test1 = new JArray(test1.Union(test2));
```

Now `test1` is

```
[
  "john",
  "doe"
]
```

Comment: This generates a new JArray, leaving the old ones intact

Answer (score 5):

My two cents for the generic case where you have `n` `JArray`'s:

```
IEnumerable<JArray> jarrays = ...
var concatenated = new JArray(jarrays.SelectMany(arr => arr));
```

And to project this onto the original question with two `JArray`'s:

```
JArray jarr0 = ...
JArray jarr1 = ...
var concatenated = new JArray(new[] { jarr0, jarr1 }.SelectMany(arr => arr));
```